# VS Xamarin cannot generate IPA files

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, ipa

I used to set the configuration to "Release|iPhone|Remote Device" , but the remote device is not showing anymore, only local device left.

Does anyone know is there any setting about it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which version of Xamarin are you using? Which is the device iOS version?

Comment: @Raptor Xamarin   16.11.000.174
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   14.20.0.25

Comment: @Raptor There is not a real physical device connected to the mac server.

Comment: What's the version of your XCode? You can try to update to the latest version. If the problem persist, try to repair your visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to Visual Studio 16.11.3.  The "Remote Device" option has been restored.  See [the release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.11.3).