# VS Xamarin Build iPhone Release don't have remote device on devices list

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I update VS2019 to 16.11.1 and lost the remote device in the list of devices when try to create a release build.

Any sugestion?
Thanks

Comment: It seems that the problem only happens in VS 16.11 , check the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826358/vs-xamarin-cannot-generate-ipa-files) , did you try to update `Xcode` as well ? If problem persists  I would suggest you downgrade VS to 16.10 .

Comment: Thanks I will wait one more day for a vs update.