# The selected ios device is not supported for creating an archive

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to setup new MacBook as a build server remotely for xamarin projects. It is in my office and I connect there with rdp from Windows 10 from home.

On MacBook: installed Xcode, Apple Developer Tools, Transporter. On windows: connected to mac, entered AppleID in visual Studio, enabled Automatic Provisioning.
Then I build my Xamarin.Forms ios project in "AppStore" configuration and it's ok.
Then I click "Archive" on that project and get error message from Visual Studio Archive Manager:

```
Selected device doesn't support archiving.
The selected ios device is not supported for creating an archive.
Please select a remote device from the drop-down menu before archiving.
```

Do I have to have iPhone to build my app? Where - in MacBook location or at home?

Archiving of a new default project works in Xcode (the active scheme is set to "Any iOS device (arm64)"). The error is in visual studio.

Visual Studio 2019 - (16.11.2)
XCode 12.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `remote device` option does not show in drop menu in VS 16.11 .

Check the similar cases : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68926454/vs-xamarin-build-iphone-release-dont-have-remote-device-on-devices-list#comment121823177_68926454) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826358/vs-xamarin-cannot-generate-ipa-files) .

Try to downgrade Visual studio to 16.10.x to see if problem persists.

You can download the older version from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#release-dates-and-build-numbers) .

Answer (score 2):

There is a new version that fixes this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The solution in 2022 is to choose "Remote Device" from the "Debug" dropdown:

[image: Remote Device]

This is hinted at in the question, but that error message no longer explains what to do (!?!)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a physical device to archive. Just click the [image: Set the active scheme] bar on the top-left of your screen, then select the <kbd>Any iOS Device</kbd> option. On older versions of Xcode, I think it was called <kbd>Generic iOS Device</kbd>. After this, hit `Product` -> `Archive` again.

[image: Any iOS Device (arm64, armv7)]

Comment: Thanks, I checked what you wrote. Everything works in xcode. But the error is in visual studio. I cleaned up the solution, updated visual studio to 16.11.2 - Nothing changed. I will now update the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Microsoft have finally released a fix for this in 16.11.3: The release notes are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.11.3